# How do I launch a search in Dynamics CRM 2011 from an SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

fairly new to SQL & coding in general with very little experience in developing SSRS reports, so please excuse me if I am a little vague.

I am trying to launch a search of our CRM directly from within a report. Currently, I can link directly to records in our CRM from SSRS dependent on the results of the report. So say for example the SSRS report brings back the address of a property '21 Transact Avenue, KY6 1LZ', I can click on the result and it will take me to that page in our CRM. So far this has been fairly simple process: The report brings back the guid of the what I want to link to, take URL, add value of GUID, works great.

However, I also wish to conduct a search within the CRM by clicking on a result from the report. Say for example the report brings back a result with the postcode 'KY6 1LZ' I wish to search all of our properties in the CRM that have that postcode. The problem is that when you search in CRM, is doesn't produce a link and as a result I am not sure how launch the search - or even if it is possible?

Im not sure what else to add to make this easier to answer, but I am happy to provide as much detail as you need to help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's some MSDN information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc905759.aspx) on utilizing URLs to access specific CRM pages. The problem I'm hearing from you is that you don't know which specific pages drives the search results. If your CRM interface has its own search or search results page, then you need to get the page name from whoever manages that server (if it's being loaded, then the page exists, even if it's just part of another page; see the link above for more information on the naming conventions you'll need to use). Then, try to find out the variables the that search results page can handle. For instance, if your searching for address, what's the URL variable to input address? is it in the form of *?address=* or *add=*?

I'm not familiar with the URL structures of CRM, so you might find that it doesn't support URL parametrization. But hopefully you'll find something that works.

If you can find out all of that information, you should be able to construct the URL from SSRS.